# TYPO3 Extbase - Download file is cut off to 40 KB if user is not logged in to the front end

Tags: model-view-controller, typo3, extbase, typo3-6.2.x

I created a duplicate of a download extension from my colleague which is basically an extension which just provides files to download in the back end.

**Problem:**

If i try to download a file while the extension is only accessible after login to the back end, then it works perfectly fine

however if I open a private browser window where I am not logged in to the back end, then it always cuts off the file and only download the first 40 KB ... even though it is normally 10 MB. Why is the file cut off?

**I can download small files ( < 40KB ) perfectly without them getting cutted off.**

> **NOTE:**
>
> **Before I edited the extension, the download worked perfectly, even if not logged in to the back end! And the download was triggered the same way**

Currently I am comparing the code, but from the logic it looks ok, since I did not changed much (added a new model, renamed the extension and some other stuff)

Does someone have a clue what can lead to this problem?

This is the relevant part in my download controller where I first get the public url of the file by passing the `fid` of the file  and then trigger the download by sending headers.

```
...
if ($this->request->hasArgument('fid')) {
    $this->fid = $this->request->getArgument('fid');
}
if ($this->request->hasArgument('cid')) {
    $this->cid = $this->request->getArgument('cid');
}

$fileobj = $this->fileRepository->findByUid($this->fid);        

if ($fileobj->getFile() !== null) {            
    $downloadFilePath = $fileobj->getFile()->getOriginalResource()->getPublicUrl();

    if (file_exists($downloadFilePath)) {
        $fileCounter = (int)$fileobj->getCounter();
        $fileobj->setCounter(++$fileCounter);
        $oldChecksum = $fileobj->getChecksume();
        $groesse = filesize($downloadFilePath);

        if (isset($oldChecksum)) {
            $checksum = sha1_file($downloadFilePath);
            $fileobj->setChecksume($checksum);
        }

        // update fileobj
        $this->fileRepository->update($fileobj);

        // Unset fileobj before persists, otherwise there will be also changes
        $this->persistenceManager->persistAll();

        // If file exists, force download
        $fileName = basename($downloadFilePath);

        $this->response->setHeader('Content-Type', "application/force-download", TRUE);
        $this->response->setHeader('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename=' . $fileName, TRUE);
        $this->response->setHeader('Content-Length', $groesse, TRUE);

        @readfile($downloadFilePath);
        $this->response->sendHeaders();
        return true; //i can also delete this line, since it is never reached.

    } else {
        //send emails to everyone who is entered in the address list in the extension configuration.
        $this->sendEmails('missing_file', $fileobj);
        $this->redirect(
            'list',
            'Category',
            NULL,
            array(
                'missing' => array(
                    'fileId' => $this->fid,
                    'category' => $this->cid
                )
            )
        );
    }
}
```

The 40 KB file does not contain anything that shouldn't be there, it is just cut off. I tested it by writing alot of numbers in a file line by line and download it, result: only a couple thousand numbers are in the file instead of all numbers.

I tried it with both, files stored at a FTP Server and files stored in user_upload, same result.

Here you can see the 40 KB file:
http://pasteall.org/459911

**Snippet (in case if the link is down):**

```
<ul>
        <li>0</li>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>3</li>
        <li>4</li>
        <li>5</li>
        <li>6</li>
        <li>7</li>
        <li>8</li>
        <li>9</li>
```

//Cut because stackoverflow does not allow me to post such big texts
            ...

```
        <li>3183</li>
        <li>3184</li>
        <li>3185</li>
        <li>3186</li>
        <li
```

You can see that it stops downloading the rest, the question is: why?

---

**UPDATE:**

I changed it to this:

```
    // If file exists, force download
    $fileName = basename($downloadFilePath);

    $this->response->setHeader('Content-Type', "application/force-download", TRUE);
    $this->response->setHeader('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename=' . $fileName, TRUE);
    $this->response->setHeader('Content-Length', $groesse, TRUE);

    ob_start();
    ob_flush();
    flush();
    $content = file_get_contents($downloadFilePath);

    $this->response->setContent($content);
    $this->response->sendHeaders();
    return true; //i can also delete this line, since it is never reached.
```

Now the file is downloaded completly, but the file is now wrapped inside the html from the template. it gets rendered inside the fluid variable `mainContent`.

Like this:

```
...

<!--TYPO3SEARCH_begin-->        
<div class="clearfix col-sm-{f:if(condition:'{data.backend_layout} == 4',then:'12',else:'9')} col-md-{f:if(condition:'{data.backend_layout} == 4',then:'9',else:'6')} col-lg-{f:if(condition:'{data.backend_layout} == 4',then:'10',else:'8')} mainContent">          
    <f:format.raw>{mainContent}</f:format.raw>        
</div>        
<!--TYPO3SEARCH_end-->

...
```

It gets weirder and weirder...

Comment: `readfile` directly writes data to the output buffer which works around the response object. You can do this, but have to ensure that headers are sent prior to the file contents. At the end of this, the system has to be stopped from further processing and outputs. A better way is to strictly use the response object for both headers and contents...

Comment: @OliverHader +1. file_get_contents reads the whole file and assigns it to the variable. Remove the output buffer commands and use readfile instead which initiates stream output through the webserver. This unfortunally means you have to transfer the http headers yourself before the download and exit the script execution instead of returning to Extbases AbstractActionController. A cleaner way is to wire a View to replace the TemplateView that instead transfers files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved the problem. I just had to execute `exit` or `die`  after sending the headers:

```
@readfile($downloadFilePath);
$this->response->sendHeaders();
exit;
```

> **NOTE**: If you exit your code with `exit` or `die` then typo3 session set with e.g. `$GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->setKey("ses", "token", DownloadUtility::getToken(32));` won't work anymore if not logged in to the backend! Use `$GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->setAndSaveSessionData("token", DownloadUtility::getToken(32));` in this case if no log in should be required.

Now it works even if not logged in to the front end.

But I still don't know why the download worked without being cut off while being logged in to the backend, even though the exit statement was missing. Thats extremly weird and we have no explanation.

Comment: The `exit` call (that's what I meant with "stop execution" in a previous comment) is essential here. Since TYPO3 continues processing even after your controller is done. That's where additional headers, outputs and e.g. debug snippets (e.g. if using the Development Context, defined in Install Toll) are added to your output. This mixture then invalidates the content, since e.g. the content is much longer or contains mixed binary and HTML data...

Comment: If having an active backend context, caching is disabled. Thus you have to check the the plugin action settings, see https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/ExtbaseFluidBook/b-ExtbaseReference/Index.html#registration-of-frontend-plugins